# Brackets Vs Parenthesis

Tags: american-english, terminology, british-english, programming

I came across this [question on Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252503/are-british-international-english-terms-acceptable-e-g-brackets-instead-of), where a discussion was going on in the comments about the terms *brackets* and *parenthesis* and the right usage of them.

It seems there is a different usage in British English and American English. Because I’m German I didn't have a clue about this and would like to know if there really is a difference.

The Oxford Dictionary denotes [brackets](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/brackets) as: ( ) and [ ], but I think { } and < > belong to this family too, where for example { } are curly-brackets.

[Parenthesis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parenthesis) is the term only for ( ).

Is this true for both British and American English? If not, where is the exact difference?

Comment: In American technical (linguistics, CS) usage, [square brackets], {curly brackets}, and <angle brackets> are varieties of _bracket_; (parentheses) function the same way, but use a different name. All are used for _bracketing_ (or _bracketting_), though the verb _to bracket_ has several other uses that don't involve [punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler This is the way I'm familiar with. Thanks for pointing this out and for the sheet!

Comment: Steve Benett, I suspect that the word "parentheses" is part of American English in particular. I have not seen or heard it used in the UK.

Comment: The problem that *parenthesis* means "putting in between", and as such it is often used to describe the **phenomenon**, instead of certain marks that are often used to effect parenthesis in writing, like `( )`. Cf. the adjective *parenthetical*. To use *parenthesis* for both the phenomenon and a particular kind of bracket is confusing and, I should say, infelicitous. We have the word bracket, which is a perfectly nice and clear word. Brackets or round brackets is what I would call `( )`, and they can be used to designate parenthesis, as can commas `, ,`, dashes `— —`, etc.

Comment: @Tristanr The OED disagrees with you: **“3a** The upright curves ( ) collectively, used to include words inserted parenthetically; now usually in pl. *parentheses*; ‘round brackets’.”  Their first citation of this sense in English is from **300 years ago** and has been in vigorous use ever since; the citations from the 19th-century *English* writers are especially revealing.

Comment: tchrist, where has it been in vigorous use? More common in the US, I suspect. During my life in the UK, including going through the education system and experiences of work, I have not seen or heard anyone use that word. It's so vigorously used here, that the first time I heard of it was on this site!

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: I would also like to point out I have *never* heard of ( ) being called parentheses in the context of math.

Comment: @tchrist - Actually, monospacing with back quotes is a good way to distinguish things like punctuation symbols without the clutter and confusion of quote marks (in part because of the colored background). Cerberus's note above is an excellent example of the effective use of this facility.

Comment: @tchrist: why not start with "Please use backticks only for their intended purpose, and not as a replacement for italics or other established formatting conventions", and then proceed to explain the intended purpose and why going beyond that is bad.  Starting out with "*never* use monospaced text" (and then needing to backtrack by admitting that there are cases where it is necessary and good) just makes it hard to take anything you say after the first sentence seriously—since it is obvious that your initial claim that we should never use backticks is false.

Answer (score 6):

In U.S. publishing, the most common terms for these punctuation marks are as follows:

> ( ) *parentheses* or *parens*
>
> [ ] *brackets* or *square brackets*
>
> { } *braces* or *curly brackets* or *set symbols*
>
> < > *angle brackets*

In some math textbooks, you may also encounter these two types of brackets:

> ⌊ ⌋ *floor brackets*
>
> ⌈ ⌉ *ceiling brackets*

[RapidTables](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.htm) has a page devoted to numerous mathematical symbols, including various types of brackets. I believe that the terminology reported there reflects U.S. naming conventions.

---

**Correction:** In a comment below, I inadvertently misstated RapidTables' description of the function of the ⌊ ⌋ and ⌈ ⌉ brackets as "rounding down" and "rounding up"; the wording that RapidTables actually uses is "rounds number to lower integer" and "rounds number to upper integer." However, tchrist (who clearly has a better grasp of the situation than I do) says in a comment below that the words "rounding up" and "rounding down" misrepresent what floor and ceiling functions do. I reproduce part of his comment here, for accuracy: "The floor and ceiling functions are not “rounding down” or “rounding up”. floor(-4.3) or ⌊ −4.3 ⌋ = −5, while ceiling(-4.3) or ⌈ −4.3 ⌉ = −4. So floor() rounds to the largest integral value not greater than , while ceiling() rounds to the smallest integral value not less than ." Thanks, tchrist!

---

*Words Into Type*, Third Edition (1974) indicates that, in U.S. publishing 40 years ago, compositors used the term *bracket* very narrowly:

> [Footnote 36] The terms *curves* and *round brackets* are never used in [U.S.] composing rooms for parentheses. The term there used is *parens*, separately designated *open paren* and *close paren*.
>
> [Footnote 37] The word *bracket* signifies only one thing to a compositor. Asking him to use a "square" bracket is unnecessary.

The terms *open paren* and *close paren* remain common in U.S. publishing today. In view of the rise of angle brackets (especially in computer coding) and the expanded use of curly brackets, however, I doubt that any surviving compositor would deem the term *square bracket* redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, that's the terms I'm used to.

Comment: 'Floor brackets' and 'ceiling brackets' are new to me. I suspect they have well-defined usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The RapidTables site says that they indicate "rounding down" and "rounding up," respectively: ⌊4.3⌋= 4 but ⌈4.3⌉= 5. I doubt that the need for them arises very often.

Comment: Thank you, Sven. In my day, square brackets were used (at least in our neck of the woods) for the round-down function.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The floor and ceiling functions are not “rounding down” or “rounding up”.  `floor(-4.3)` or ⌊ −4.3 ⌋ = −5, while `ceiling(-4.3)` or ⌈ −4.3 ⌉ = −4. So **floor()** rounds to the largest integral value not greater than ****, while **ceiling()** rounds to the smallest integral value not less than ****.  This is not rounding up or down.  It is something else altogether, and is much better defined.  If you want rounding towards zero, use integer truncation.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about common general usage and not someone who works in publishing, programming or mathematics, then this is the basic difference:

```
Symbol     American English                British English
------     ----------------                ---------------
()         parentheses                     brackets *or* round brackets
[]         brackets *or* square brackets   square brackets
```

The confusion is because "brackets" mean () in the US and [] in the UK. So it's better to be clear and say "square brackets" when you mean the square kind.

However, if you want the round kind, the term "round brackets" is not commonly used in the US (again, by "normal people" who don't work in a specialized industry) and the common person would not know what you mean by this. "Parentheses" would be the common name in the US.

Comment: Your first sentence has accidentally swapped symbol pairs.

Answer (score 3):

In ordinary British English, *brackets* denotes '()': they may also be called parentheses, but that is a formal word. '[]' and '{}' are *square brackets* and *curly brackets* (or *braces*) - loosely, they may all be called brackets, but as I say, the word usually means the curved ones. I would not think of '<>' as any kind of bracket: until computer programming, I don't believe they were ever used as delimiters in that way.

As you say, American usage seems to be different.

Comment: If you say the word `bracket` may be used to call these punctuations as a genus, is there also a different term for these?

Comment: It's not just formal, it's very rare. I haven't heard the word "parentheses" used in the UK.

Comment: _Inequality signs_ (<>) were probably not used for bracketing before computer programming; but the similar _single guillemets_ (‹›) and _chevrons_ (〈〉) have been in use much longer, just not very commonly in English: single guillemets function as single quotation marks in the many languages that use guillemets as the default (or possible) quotation marks, most notably French (not technically bracketing as such); while chevrons are used within the field of linguistics to mark graphemes (actual bracketing), as well as having various meanings in maths, physics, and other areas.